# EF6, Code First. How to set alternative data source for GridControl column using XAML Devexpress

Tags: wpf, xaml, entity-framework-6, devexpress, dxgrid

I have two related entities:

```
public class Event
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string EventData { get; set; } 
    public string DocID1 { get; set; }
    public int DocID2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Document Document1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Document Document2 { get; set; }

}

public class Document
{

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

}
```

Also created List to display data in WPF:

```
private ObservableCollection<Event> eventList;
public ObservableCollection<Event> EventList
        {
            get { return eventList; }
            set
            {
                if (value != eventList)
                {
                    eventList = value;
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EventList));
            }
        }
```

data for my EventList is taken from entity Event:

```
var query = DBContext.Events.Select(x => x).AsQueryable();
EventList = query.ToList();
```

What I need is how to set GridControl Column "colFirstName" value to be equal "Document1.FirstName" if DocID1 is not null and "Document2.FirstName" if DocID2 is not null. My XAML code for GridControl is below, could You help how to do it in Xaml, not in ViewModel, or if there is no way to do it in Xaml, what is the best way to do it in ViewModel.

```
<dxg:GridControl AutoPopulateColumns="False"
ItemsSource="{Binding EventList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                            <dxg:GridColumn
                                x:Name="colEventData"
                                Width="120"
                                FieldName="EventData"
                                 Header =" Event data"
                                Visible="True" >
                        </dxg:GridColumn>

                        <dxg:GridColumn
                                x:Name="colFirsnName"
                                Width="120"
                                FieldName="Document1.FirstName"
                                Header="First Name"
                                Visible="True"
                                VisibleIndex="1" />
                          </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                        </dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [UnboundExpression](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridColumnBase_UnboundExpressiontopic) property to create a column with a [custom expression](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocumen). For example, to conditionally show values from different properties, use the **Iif** function:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CustomColumn" x:Name="colFirsnName" 
                UnboundExpression="Iif(IsNullOrEmpty([DocID1]), [Document2.FirstName], [Document1.FirstName])" 
                UnboundType="String"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of logic should be implemented in the model or view model class. Remember that XAML is only a *markup* language.

Just create another property that returns the first match and bind to this one. If your entity classes are auto-generated, you could create a new partial class:

```
public partial class Event
{
    public string DocName
    {
        get
        {
            if (Document1 != null)
                return Document1.FirstName;

            if (Document2 != null)
                return Document1.LastName;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<dxg:GridColumn
    x:Name="colFirsnName"
    Width="120"
    FieldName="DocName"
    Header="First Name"
    Visible="True"
    VisibleIndex="1" IsReadOnly="true" />
```